# Why does it give an error in the react lifecycle methods if I am not using them?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a project with `react.js` to learn `redux`. It is basically a Login and a main page. I use `react-router-dom` to redirect between components, `redux` to manage the state and to know if the user is logged or not and also `redux-thunk`, to make the request async.

When the user has entered their credentials, and presses the login button, a request is made to an API. If the API responds true, with redux, I change `authUser` from false to true and through `history.push()` redirect it to the component in the path `/`.

After the login button is pressed, and if the credentials are correct you should redirect to the path `/`, which has Layout as the component to render.

This is the code of the main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Login from "../../views/Login/Login.js";
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout";

const RestrictedRoute = ({component: Component, authUser, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authUser
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect
            to={‌{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {from: props.location}
            }}
        />}
    />
  );
}

class Main extends Component {
  render () {
    const { authUser, match, history } = this.props;
    if (authUser) {
      history.push("/");
    }
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
        <RestrictedRoute path={`${match.url}`} authUser={authUser}                         component={Layout}/>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authUser: state.authUser,
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

And this is the `Layout` component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import "perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css";

import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

import Footer from "../../components/UI/Footer/Footer";

import dashboardStyle from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/layouts/dashboardStyle";

class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
    const { classes, match } = this.props;
    console.log(match);
    return (
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes.mainPanel} ref="mainPanel">
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              Layout
            </div>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(Layout);
```

And this is how a set the state with redux:

```
export const goLogin = async (data) => {
  const login = await instance.post(`/route`, data);
  if (login.status) {
    return {
      type: types.LOG_IN,
      authUser: true
    }
  }
}

 export const onLogIn = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(await goLogin(data))
  }
}
```

But then, I get this error:

> "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Is it a problem with the way I go to the server and set the state in redux?

In the console looks like it enters in a loop:

[Loop in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuhiM.png)

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGTq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `authUser` is true then `history.push("/");` will cause a rerender and an infinite loop.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344241/9602863) to a similar question.

Comment: Yeah, it was all the problem. I just implemented "componentDidUpdate" and it all worked.