# Why I receive this error using componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, infinite-loop

Receive error: ×
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Tried to delete part with error and setState (because it looks like the reason of infinite loop). Didn't help

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated){
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    }
    // if(nextProps.errors){
    //     this.setState({
    //         errors: nextProps.errors
    //     })
    //     console.log('Error');
    // }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this could be causing the error, could you please post the rest of the code for this component?

Answer (score 3):

`history.push` causes a rerender, it calls `componentWillReceiveProps` and everything goes in a loop.

Use this code instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (
      this.props.auth.isAuthenticated
      && this.props.auth.isAuthenticated !== prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated
  ) {
    this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
  }
}
```

This can still cause a loop if you have a similar mistake somewhere else.